# Continuous deployment in EC2 using Codeship

Tags: git, deployment, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

It's my first time trying to do deployment. I'm using [Codeship](http://codeship.com) for deploy a Python project in AWS EC2. I have setup a git repository on Bitbucket, but I'm not sure how to deploy to EC2. It seems to support S3 (perhaps to upload packages to S3), but doesn't seem to indicate what to do with EC2. Should I write a 'Custom script' that simply calls `git remote ...` and `git push`? Here's the screen I'm seeing.

[image]

Please help me out with this.

Comment: EC2 basically provides you with a server instance. Depending on the software you are running on the instance you could deploy doing a `git push`, but also using a tool like [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) or `rsync`. See https://codeship.com/documentation/continuous-deployment/ for documentation on using these with Codeship.

If you want to build custom AMI images with your software already included you'd need to take a look at a software like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/)

If you have any other questions, feel free to reach out to support@codeship.com and we'll help you get started!

Answer (score 0):

This blog post should give you an idea on how to do what you want:

https://blog.codeship.com/aws-codedeploy-codeship/

It uses the CodeDeploy service from AWS, and automates the creation of a deployment artifact on S3 for you.